# Mean Copernicus landcover in multiple polygons with reduceRegions

Tags: land-cover, reducers, sentinel, reduceregion

I would like to estimate the average tree cover for each polygon of a Feature Collection, but the code below only returns empty values.  I have tried using different Image Collections (like EVI) and the code works.  There seems to be an issue with how I am using the 'COPERNICUS/Landcover/100m/Proba-V-C3/Global'  collection but I am not sure.

```
// Load a FeatureCollection of counties in Maine.
var maineCounties = ee.FeatureCollection('TIGER/2016/Counties')
  .filter(ee.Filter.eq('STATEFP', '23'));

// Load input imagery: Copernicus tree cover.
var treecover = ee.Image('COPERNICUS/Landcover/100m/Proba-V-C3/Global/2019').select('tree-coverfraction').double();

var zonecover = treecover.reduceRegions({
  collection: maineCounties,
  reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
  scale: 100 
});

print(zonecover);

Export.table.toDrive({collection: zonecover});
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have noted, specifying the 'crs:' argument is important here.  Copernicus landcover data is epsg:3857 and specifying this crs will not work.  Specifying 'EPSG:4326' working in this case.